# 'qnetworkreply' has not been declared

Tags: blackberry-10, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-eclipse-plugin, blackberry-qnx

This is my code but it is giving me error "'qnetworkreply' has not been declared" .Can any one tell why it is so

```
#ifndef ApplicationUI_HPP_
#define ApplicationUI_HPP_

#include <QObject>
namespace bb { namespace cascades { class Application; }}

class ApplicationUI : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    ApplicationUI(bb::cascades::Application *app);
    virtual ~ApplicationUI() {}

    public slots:
    void onResult(QNetworkReply*);
};


#endif
```

Comment: did you include : #include <QtNetwork> in your .h ?

Comment: i add it now and it is giving me "fatal error: QtNetwork: No such file or directory"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you add : `QT += network` in your .pro file ?

Comment: now it is giving me Permission Denied when i build my programm

Comment: did you make a build on root before ? Just clean all and build with user. Look at rights over files in directoy.

Comment: I restart my computer with administrator privileges now it is building and running fine.